# How do I swap another Wordpress background per page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using this code to change my background on 1 page:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?
>/images/<?php
if(is_page('PAGE1')){ ?>goldBG.jpg') #000 no-repeat;"<?php }

else { ?>blackBG.jpg') #000 no-repeat;"<?php } ?> >
```

I want to add a 2rd page specific background, what is wrong with his code?

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?
>/images/<?php
if(is_page('PAGE1')){ ?>goldBG.jpg') #000 no-repeat;"<?php }

elseif(is_page('PAGE2')){ ?>goldBG.jpg') #000 no-repeat;"<?php }

else { ?>blackBG.jpg') #000 no-repeat;"<?php } ?> >
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Your images looks similar for Page1v& page2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Neater Example:

```
<?php
   $image = '';
   if(is_page('PAGE1')){
    $image.= "goldBG.jpg";
    }
    elseif(is_page('PAGE2')){
    $image.= "goldBG.jpg";
    }else {
        $image.= "blackBG.jpg";
    }

?>


<body <?php body_class(); ?> style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo $image; ?>')">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the code you have here you can use WordPress's [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function to return you a generated class for that specific page. You can then add this class definition in your CSS stylesheet and apply the specific background there.